# Get Chart.Series points to an array C#

Tags: c#, plot, charts, points

I am creating a program that shows a Fourier Transform and plots the points to a graph. I'm trying to get user input and each time then enter a number into the array, it will update the whole graph based on the points.

Because the chart displays the transformed values, I need to get the points from the Chart.Series, convert them back using inverse Fourier, clear the Chart, then add all values obtained from the chart, add the new value inserted by the user, then run Fourier again and add the plots to the graph.

I was wondering if there was a way in C# to get the [x,y] values of a plot and then get just the [y] values from that.

--Edit--

```
 private void inputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("The calculations are complete", "My Application",
        //                    MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

       // get information here from the graph

       // save data to an array

       // clear the series

       // then add the new data to the freq array
        double[] freq = { 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 15, 2 };

        double[] A = new double[freq.Length];

        A = halfFourierTransform(freq, freq.Length);

        HFTChart.Series[0].Points.Clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < freq.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            HFTChart.Series["HFT"].Points.AddY(A[i]);
        }

        // To work with new data each time
        // HFTChart.Series[0].Points.Clear();


    }
```

Comment: Um, I don't understand. If you are using the `Chart` control each `DataPoint` of the `Points` collection of each `Series` has a `double DataPoint.XValue` and one or more `double DataPoint.YValues[index]` , provided you have added them with valid X-Values.

Comment: I run: for each element in the double array, `chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddY(A[i]);`

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @TaW added some code for ya

Comment: If you want to control the X-Values use the AddXY overload!

Comment: Ok I put it in and it works to plot still. I'm just about to head home and I will try it when I get back and let you know how it goes @TaW